# Unity rotate camera behind player

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

I have the camera set to follow the player in 3D space, independent of the player's rotation.  Now, when a  key is pressed, I would like the camera to rotate around the player (preferably lerping) until it is facing the same direction as the player (essentially at the player's back).

I can control the rotation pretty easily using RotateAround, but I'm having some trouble getting it to stop when the camera's rotation matches that of the player, and I don't even know how to go about including the easing.  I'm assuming I would have to use Slerp, but I don't know how to use that in tandem with RotateAround.

Any information or resources would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if this would help you but it sounds like you know the angle and position that you need to go, right? You can choose a point that is relative to the player (F.E: a new gameobject inside the player?). Is not the most optimal solution but I think that could work.

Comment: It sounds like you've already made some attempts to solve this problem - can you share the code for your best one here, so we can look over it and determine how to best get it working properly?

Comment: I agree with Cabrra. Just add a G.O. as a child of the player and create a  trigger box collider for it. When the camera enters it, stop it.

Comment: You really shouldn't use colliders for stuff like that as suggested here. You can just calculate the angle between the cameras looking direction and the players looking direction (if these objects are on different heights, project them into the same plane). Stop rotating when the angle approaches 0. This angle can also be used for controlling the rotation speed (for easing)

Comment: I think I've done something like this before, and I can probably help, but I give a 95% chance it will be a modification to your current camera-follow code, which means I need to know what your camera-follow code is doing. Are you setting its position to the player's position + a constant Vector3 every frame? Are you using Transform hierarchy shenanigans? Are you using a Standard Assets script or Rigidbody joints or something completely different?

Comment: @xyLe_ There is nothing incorrect about using trigger colliders for this purpose (Or pretty much any purpose). Saying something 'shouldn't' be done but providing no insight, no reason or explanation is not beneficial. If you think something is incorrect, make a case. S/O is not for opinion.

Comment: @jjhavokk when using colliders for this, you are issuing the physics engine a lot, which is definately more costly than just doing a bit of math. Next thing is, that triggers are bound to the fixed update step, whereas you can (but not necessarily) achieve smoother movement using the normal update step. I am generally not against alienating stuff, but you should ask yourself if you should do so or if there is a more convenient way to solve your issue.

Comment: @xyLe_ Neither operation is costly in any sense. Bound checking between two cube colliders is trivial mathematically speaking. Is tracking angles a better solution? Probably. Is a trigger collider the way I would go in my games? Absolutely not. I was simply trying to provide an easy solution as it appears to be a beginner question. More importantly, nobody has answered the question yet!

Answer (score 0):

How about remembering camera offset from player and lerping position with `transform.LookAt(target)` where target is a player or a point in front of him?